# SQLAlchemy equivalent to Django's x.objects.extra()?

Tags: python, sql, django, sqlalchemy

I just learned of django's (model).objects.extra() function, as documented:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/querysets/#extra

I'm hoping that there is something similar in sqlalchemy.  I would like to be able to have the flexibility of raw sql through the cursor, but still have my results come back through the ORM.

Can you force SQL code into your query? (I'm using declarative base by the way)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for `Query.from_statement`: http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.from_statement

Comment: This sounds perfect, I should have seen it.  As soon as I get to this project and test it I'm sure I'll accept this answer.  Thank you.